# Is there a Protostuff-equivalent Protobuff library for Python?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, protobuf-python

In Java, libraries like `protostuff` allow you to generate buffers from a Java POJO approximately like so:

```java
Schema<Foo> schema = RuntimeSchema.getSchema(Foo.class);
...
protostuff = ProtostuffIOUtil.toByteArray(foo, schema, buffer);
```

I've been trying to find a similar solution for Python, but except for attempting to  programmatically build `Descriptors` and `FieldDescriptors` (which come with their own challenges and problems since `4.x.x`), I couldn't find anything. Is this simply impossible in Python, just isn't implemented anywhere, or am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative Python protobuf libraries of [pure-protobuf](https://github.com/eigenein/protobuf) and [python-betterproto](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/python-betterproto) both have their own syntax that can be used directly from Python, without a `.proto` file.

It however doesn't work for completely plain Python objects, as you still need to specify the field types and tag numbers (example from pure-protobuf):

```
@message
@dataclass
class SearchRequest:
    query: str = field(1, default='')
    page_number: int32 = field(2, default=int32(0))
    result_per_page: int32 = field(3, default=int32(0))
```